# Has anyone actually got ROS working on Mac OS X Sierra?

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, mac, homebrew

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that ROS Kinetic or Lunar are "experimental" on OS X (Homebrew), but what does that mean? Does it mean that someone has actually been able to get it installed and simulate a simple robot on Mac? I have been following the steps at https://gist.github.com/jmtatsch/44e7c1a55fc29432254bdc61559d91c7 "ROS Kinetic on Sierra Work in Progress" on a FRESH install (system completely wiped and reinstalled) Mac OS X Sierra, but I am running into some difficulties:

When I perform the step `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y`, I get an error message `robot: Missing resource robot`, which I find interesting because presumably it should find the robot metapackage easily within the `src/metapackages` folder. Under the assumption that "maybe this isn't that big of a deal", I continued with the installation steps outlined in the Github, but I am having issues with the step:

```
catkin build \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib \
  -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

It fails almost immediately on:

```
Failed     << cpp_common:cmake                                [ Exited with code 1 ]                    
Failed    <<< cpp_common                                      [ 0.2 seconds ]

Errors     << cpp_common:cmake /Users/karl/ros_catkin_ws/logs/cpp_common/build.cmake.000.log            
CMake Error at /Users/karl/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findconsole_bridge.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "console_bridge", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "console_bridge"
  with any of the following names:

    console_bridgeConfig.cmake
    console_bridge-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "console_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "console_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "console_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

Why is it even looking for `console_bridge` in Kinetic? I thought `console_bridge` was replaced with `rosconsole_bridge`? Why would there still be a dependency?

The reasons I can't just install ROS on a Linux box natively are (1) all I have are Mac systems, (2) I can't afford a Linux workstation with suitable performance right now, and (3) I can use a Linux VPS remotely, but applications like Gazebo do not seem to graphically perform well remotely through VNC (I tried this before). What would you recommend?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268040/has-anyone-actually-got-ros-working-on-mac-os-x-sierra?/) by [Cataphract](https://answers.ros.org/users/31427/cataphract/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-04**:\

> Has anyone actually got ROS working on Mac OS X Sierra?

If #q267326 is any indication it doesn't seem like this is easy.

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-04-23**:
For Lunar on OSX:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/263010/any-success-w-lunar-on-mac-os-x/
- https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I eventually gave up on running ROS under Homebrew, and instead decided to dual boot my Mac with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This wasn't very difficult to do with the guides on using ReEFIt.

---

Originally posted by [Cataphract](https://answers.ros.org/users/31427/cataphract/) with karma: 86 on 2017-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2